# Akka remoting - asking routee doesn't return answer

Tags: scala, playframework, akka, remoting

I am trying to `ask` something to an actor that has been created remotely in a `SmallestMailboxPool` but I never seem to get a response. My feeling is that this is because I send the message to the `Router`, but the `Routee` is the actor that is responding - not knowing the exact internals of Akka's ask, I can imagine that the replied must be the same as where the message was sent to. On the other hand, this seems so rudimentary that I cannot imagine it wouldn't work.

I am using Play framework 2.3.x and Akka remote 2.3.4

**Actor Setup**
I have 2 machines with 2 actors on these machines. I will try to keep the example as brief as possible.

*Machine A/Actor A*

The actual ask is being initiated on Machine A, I added some `println` statements to show actor addresses. The code is as follows.

```
class ActorA(remoteActor: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    ...
    def receive() = {
        case a: String => {
            println("Remote actor: " + remoteActor)
            println("Self: " + self)
            // This is where I get a timeout because I never get a reply
            Await.result((remoteActor ? a), timeout.duration)
        }
    }
}
```

The output I am getting on Machine A is the following:

```
Remote actor: Actor[akka.tcp://application@192.168.0.101:2552/user/actorB_6f9bac20-2302-4408-9a1b-feece8c20bc3#-1920529606]
Self: Actor[akka://application/user/9df0190a-11fb-438c-9124-4869d015fc4d#-867250738]
```

Note that the `ActorRef` I am passing on to ActorA (called `remoteActor`), is the `val actorRef` that I create on Machine B (see below), having the MailboxPool.

*Machine B/Actor B*

On Machine B, I have an Actor B that is created in a SmallestMailboxPool and recieves the message from Actor A (via the Router) after which it replies.

The creation is as follows:

```
// Creation of the mailbox/Router
val actorRef = Akka.system.actorOf(
    SmallestMailboxPool(1).props(
        // sourceActor is the actorRef of Actor A, living on machine A
        Props(ActorB, sourceActor)
    ),
    name = java.util.UUID.randomUUID.toString
)
println("Mailbox is: " + actorRef)
```

The actual Actor B does the following:

```
class ActorB(sourceActor: ActorRef) extends Actor with ActorLogging {
    println("I am: " + self)
    def receive() = {
        case a: String => {
            println("I got data from " + sender)
            println("Sending it back to: " + sourceActor)
            sourceActor ! d
        }
    }
}
```

What I am getting from Actor B is the following printlines:

```
Mailbox is Actor[akka://application/user/actorB_6f9bac20-2302-4408-9a1b-feece8c20bc3#-1920529606]
I am Actor[akka://application/user/actorB_6f9bac20-2302-4408-9a1b-feece8c20bc3/$a#46262703]
I got data from Actor[akka.tcp://application@192.168.0.132:2552/temp/$e]
I am sending it back to: Actor[akka.tcp://application@192.168.0.132:2552/user/9df0190a-11fb-438c-9124-4869d015fc4d#-867250738]
```

So what I don't get is why the actor address from ActorA appears as `temp/$e` on ActorB's side. As can also be seen, ActorB gets the message from ActorA, which actually sends it to the Router. ActorB then rightfully tries to reply back to ActorA, but it always gets a timeout - is this because ActorB has a different ActorRef/address than the Router/Mailbox? I also tried sending back to `sender` instead of the parameter-given `sourceActor`, but to no avail.

I know I can ask the Mailbox for all its Routees and send an ask directly to them (haven't tried this yet), but that defies the whole purpose of a MailboxPool. **EDIT**: Tried this, didn't work either

**EDIT:**

The weirdest of this entire story, is that if I create `ActorB` on machine A (eg. not remotely), everything works just fine - I can ask the Router's `ActorRef` and I get a proper reply. As soon as `ActorB` is created on machine B, I never get a reply anymore. I also tried to see what happens if I just `tell` `ActorB` and continue in `ActorA` without caring for the result. What happens then is that I **do** get the message from `ActorB` that should be my response to the original ask... `ActorB` is hence perfectly capable of sending back to `ActorA` but for some reason, Akka won't use it as the reply to my original ask...

Comment: Can you provide the code that produces the ActorRef you are passing into ActorA?  Also, what is `remoteGenerator`?

Comment: I fixed the typo, `remoteGenerator` is remoteActor. I also added the code that I use to get remoteActor from (the ActorRef I pass on to ActorA) - it's the result of the `val actorRef = ...` that I execute on machine B

Comment: Can you please show how `sourceActor` and `remoteActor` are created?  Namely, `val sourceActor = ...` and `val remoteActor = ...` .

Answer (score 0):

I managed to get it work. Turns out I was passing around an ActorRef to ActorB to which it was supposed to send, but at ask-time from ActorA, it seems like Akka makes some sort of temp actor that actually needs to be sent to from ActorB (ie. I can't just send to the ActorRef of ActorA that I passed on to ActorB and stored earlier). Using `sender` was a fix for me. (Although I am still puzzled why `sender` was actually not my ActorA).

My actual use case is far too complex to share on SO, but I made a small example (where this problem doesn't occur - everything works) for people interested: https://github.com/ErikTromp/AkkaRemoteAskTest. It uses Play's Iteratee library too, since that is part of my use case too.